# ReadwriteTimeout in FileWebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

I use the following code to increase the timeout from a webrequest:

```
_timeout=150000;
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    request.Timeout = _timeout;
    if (request is HttpWebRequest) ((HttpWebRequest)request).ReadWriteTimeout = request.Timeout;
    return request;
}
```

this works fine for `http*://` - Uris
But when I have a `file://` - uri the `WebRequest` isn't a `HttpWebRequest` but a `FileWebRequest`. Now my problem is: A `FileWebRequest` does *not* have a `ReadWriteTimeout`-Property. 
How can this be achieved in FileWebRequests?

(update) As you can see on my example, I already use the `Timeout`-Property but this is not the property I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the `Timeout` property the one you are looking for?
[FileWebRequest - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (on the bottom of the page there is even an example with the Timeout)

Comment: At least on the HttpWebRequest the Timeout is the timeout until the server **responds** and not the Timeout for **downloading** a file. And according to the describtion on your link this is the same on a fileWebRequest

Comment: Or to put it in other words: Without the ReadWriteTimeout-Property I receive a TimoutException on big files.

Comment: Are you getting timeout exception when you set `.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite` ?

Comment: I've set it up to an hour but get a timeout after about 10 minutes when calling WebClient.DownloadFile()